# How animateAlongsideTransition work?

Tags: swift, ios8, uiviewanimationtransition

This is my part of my subclass of `UIPresentationController`:

```
override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {

    if let containerView = containerView {
        dimmingView.frame = containerView.bounds
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        containerView.insertSubview(dimmingView, atIndex: 0)

        presentedViewController.transitionCoordinator()?.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in

            self.dimmingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() //line A

            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I cannot see the yellow even for a millisecond. Why? What does it mean **alongside transition?** What transition? My transition duration is set within `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` to **5 seconds**.

If I remove my **line A**, then I can see just yellow color and it is ok. Why this animation (from yellow to green) do not take my 5 seconds?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I haven't found it yet.